# ASP VB - How to update a database where the selected item is from a dropdown list using a datasource

Tags: asp.net

Hi I am new to ASP and was able to create a dropdown list which list all the items from my table `(DB2_INSTANCES)`.

Now I need to update a second table (`PROCESS`) with the value selected DB2_DSN. `The table does not allow Null values`.

If I use `"SelectedValue='<%# Bind("DB2_DSN") %>'` within my `asp:DropDownList` after I set the

`DataSourceID="SqlDataSource6"  DataTextField="INSTANCE"  DataValueField="INSTANCE"`

I get an error:

> "'DropDownList6' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value "

If I change to `"SelectedValue='<%# Bind("INSTANCE") %>'` within my `asp:DropDownList` after I set the

`DataSourceID="SqlDataSource6"  DataTextField="INSTANCE"  DataValueField="INSTANCE"`

I get an error:

> "DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'INSTANCE'."

If I remove the "`SelectedValue`..." I get the error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'DB2_DSN', table 'xxx.dbo.PROCESS'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
>   The statement has been terminated.

I also tried using the `DataBind()` but it also gives me an error. 
The other value `(FTP_IND)` works fine because it is listed/hardcoded.
Why does it work for `FTP_IND` and not for `DB2_DSN`?

First:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:xxxConnectionString2 %>" 
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM PROCESS WHERE NAME = @NAME AND ENVIRONMENT =   @ENVIRONMENT"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [PROCESS]" 
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE PROCESS SET ENVIRONMENT = @ENVIRONMENT, PROCESS_STATUS = @PROCESS_STATUS, IC_VALUE = @IC_VALUE, 
    FTP_IND = @FTP_IND, DB2_DSN = @DB2_DSN, DB2_REGION = @DB2_REGION, 
    ALERT_EMAIL = @ALERT_EMAIL, NOTIFY_EMAIL = @NOTIFY_EMAIL, DEBUG_INFO = @DEBUG_INFO, 
    LAST_UPDATE_DATE = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, LAST_UPDATE_USERID = @UID, LAST_UPDATE_IP = @UIP WHERE (NAME = @NAME)">
        <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter Name="UID" SessionField="User_ID" Type="String" />
        <asp:SessionParameter Name="UIP" SessionField="User_IP" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ENVIRONMENT" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="PROCESS_STATUS" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="IC_VALUE" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="FTP_IND" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="DB2_DSN" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="DB2_REGION" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ALERT_EMAIL" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="NOTIFY_EMAIL" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="DEBUG_INFO" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="NAME" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource6" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:xxxConnectionString2 %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [INSTANCE] FROM [DB2_INSTANCES] ORDER BY [INSTANCE] ASC">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Second:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FTP" SortExpression="FTP_IND">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList5" runat="server"  
                    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("FTP_IND") %>' 
                    ToolTip="Use this to turn off and on the FTP process" Font-Size="Small">
                    <asp:ListItem>N</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Y</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FTP_IND") %>' 
                    ToolTip="Indicates if FTP will take place" Font-Size="Small">
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "DB2 Instance" SortExpression="DB2_DSN">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList6" runat="server" 
                    ToolTip="Use this to choose the DB2 Instance" Font-Size="Small" 
                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource6"
                    DataTextField="INSTANCE" 
                    DataValueField="INSTANCE">
                 </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DB2_DSN") %>'
                    ToolTip="Indicates the DB2 Instance being used" Font-Size="Small">
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
```

Comment: I was able to figure out the issue. The SelectedValue='<%# Bind("DB2_DSN") %>' needed to be part of the DropDownList code. The column table needed to be set as VARCHAR(5) instead of CHAR(5) because if the data only had 3 bytes it could not find the match. Once the column type was changed it worked.

Comment: This was answered by myself. Not sure how to flag it!